# making two tables depending if they have 0 or 1

Tags: php, mysql

essentially I want to have two tables one with everyone with Confirmed = 1 and the other with Confirmed = 0.

I have this sql query at the moment

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE $row[Confirmed] = 1");
```

but I keep getting

```
Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

rest of the code for that page

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>BookID</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>time</th>
<th>confirmed?</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
  { ?>
   <tr>
   <td> <?php echo $row['tbl_mem_id']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['date']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['time']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['Confirmed']; ?> </td>
   <td> <a href=delete.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </a> Delete </td>
   <td> 
       <?php
       if ($row['Confirmed'] == 0) { ?>
       <a href=confirm.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </a> Confirm </td> <?php } else { ?>
       <a href=deny.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </a> Deny </td> <?php
       } ?>
   </tr> <?php
  } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Missing quotes? `$row['Confirmed']`

Comment: @TobiasKun qoutes not required.

Comment: that adds more errors than it fixes.

Comment: And curly brackets? {$row['Confirmed']}

Comment: have you declared $result in that page ?

Comment: Well then paste the code before `$result`

Comment: Outside of the loop `$row` is not defined.

Comment: It difficult to understand why u use this WHERE statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you really trying to put the value in `$row['Confirmed']` in the query, or are you just trying to query a field named `Confirmed`? if its the latter try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE Confirmed= 1");
```

but since also you seem to differentiate the table in php with `if ($row['Confirmed'] == 0)` you probably need to get all data in one query with this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_booking");
```

this won't give you 2 tables as you initially asked for though.

you can create 2 html tables with this:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE Confirmed = 1");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>BookID</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>time</th>
<th>confirmed?</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
  { ?>
   <tr>
   <td> <?php echo $row['tbl_mem_id']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['date']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['time']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['Confirmed']; ?> </td>
   <td> <a href=delete.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </a> Delete </td>
   <td> 

       <a href=deny.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </a> Deny </td>

   </tr> <?php
  } ?>
</table>
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>BookID</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>time</th>
<th>confirmed?</th>
</tr>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE Confirmed = 0 ");    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
  { ?>
   <tr>
   <td> <?php echo $row['tbl_mem_id']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['date']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['time']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row['Confirmed']; ?> </td>
   <td> <a href=delete.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </a> Delete </td>
   <td> 
       <a href=confirm.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?> </a> Confirm </td>
   </tr> <?php
  } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I didn't really make this clear enough, mybad. Basically Im trying to create a table at the moment that checks the $row['confirmed'] and see's if its 1 and if it is echo's that information into a table. the other one is going to be all with confirmed = 0 but once I understand how one works I think i can do the other.

Comment: Better create table like that `create table tbl_booking_confirmed as select * from tbl_booking where Confirmed = 1`.

Comment: Oh, maybe by `create table` you meant display separate html table?

Comment: @user3013008 first of all, what is the value in `$row['Confirmed']`, it SHOULD be a column name or a number for that query to actually run. just print out the query and paste here

Comment: added 2 html table version to my answer.